# Rails 5 app with Puma and Nginx - 111: Connection refused while connecting to upstream, client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2, puma

I an getting this error:

```
2016/09/29 01:05:39 [error] 7169#0: *3 connect() to unix:/home/deploy/tasks/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 99.254.197.158, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/deploy/tasks/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock:/", host: "ec2-54-88-181-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

When trying to use this URL for my app:

```
http://ec2-54-88-181-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
```

The browser also presents the this message:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.
```

However I am able to access my app when using Puma directly on port 3000 using this URL:

```
http://ec2-54-88-181-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3000/
```

And I am able to navigate through all pages of the app this way.

Here are some of my configuration files:

```
$ ls -l /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 Sep 28 22:46 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default


$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
[sudo] password for deploy: 
user root; #www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
upstream app {
    # Path to Puma SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/deploy/tasks/shared/tmp/sockets/puma.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/deploy/tasks/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

The server is listening on ports 80, 22 and 3000 (for Puma)

```
$ netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0    280 172.31.51.143:22        99.254.197.158:60843    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.51.143:22        99.254.197.158:60842    ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.51.143:59545     172.31.47.0:5432        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.31.51.143:59544     172.31.47.0:5432        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:55159           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::12784                :::*
```

Nginx and Puma are running.

```
$ ps -ef | grep nginx
root      1644  1586  0 01:21 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
root      1645  1644  0 01:21 pts/0    00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
root      1698     1  0 01:39 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
root      1701  1698  0 01:39 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root      1702  1698  0 01:39 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root      1703  1698  0 01:39 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root      1704  1698  0 01:39 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
deploy    1736  1309  0 02:13 pts/1    00:00:00 grep nginx


$ ps -ef | grep puma
deploy    1564     1  0 01:20 ?        00:00:00 puma 3.6.0 (tcp://0.0.0.0:3000) [20160928212850]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
deploy    1571  1564  0 01:20 ?        00:00:01 puma: cluster worker 0: 1564 [20160928212850]
```

I am deploying with Capistrano to an AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 server.
There are no errors related to deployments.

I fetched all blogs / post I found but none of these solutions there worked for me so far.

What I shall try next in order to have the Nginx server working?

Comment: Can you share the error/server logs...

Comment: Which one of these? 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-51-143:/var/log$ ls -1 
alternatives.log 
apt 
auth.log 
auth.log.1 
boot.log 
btmp 
cloud-init.log 
cloud-init-output.log 
dist-upgrade 
dmesg 
dmesg.0 
dmesg.1.gz 
dmesg.2.gz 
dmesg.3.gz 
dmesg.4.gz 
dpkg.log 
fsck 
kern.log 
kern.log.1 
landscape 
lastlog 
nginx 
postgresql 
syslog 
syslog.1 
syslog.2.gz 
syslog.3.gz 
syslog.4.gz 
syslog.5.gz 
udev 
unattended-upgrades 
upstart 
wtmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrapped the AWS EC2 instance and recreate it using and Ubuntu 14.04 implementation which I upgraded to 16.04. I followed strictly the guidance found here

http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-puma-capistrano-nginx-jungle-upstart/
and related links from the same blog.

Now Nginx and Puma are working properly together and my app runs perfectly here:

http://ec2-54-159-156-217.compute-1.amazonaws.com/
The only difference form the guidelines is that I kept the AWS RDS instance for the database. I used RVM in the production server although I am using RBENV on my Mac. I used ubuntu user (like root) for deployment since I am suspecting all the troubles I had were related to permissions and I did not know how to fix them.

Many errors encountered earlier trying to start properly Puma on socket and make it working with Nginx, especially not restarting after

cap production deploy
were related to generating the secret and putting this value in the appropiate file. For me it worked the best writing it in the /etc/environment file.

I also did changes in the file /etc/ssh/sshd_config in order to get root or ubuntu access through ssh. In this matter this link

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=86876
was very useful.

Comment: regrettably the 
http://codepany.com/blog/rails-5-puma-capistrano-nginx-jungle-upstart/ no longer works :(